# pandas read multi-index dataframe ( reverse to_string() )

Tags: pandas

I have a text-file which looks like this:

**test2.dat:**

```
               col1      col2
idx1 idx2                    
a    0     0.256788  0.862771
     1     0.409944  0.785159
     2     0.822773  0.955309
b    0     0.159213  0.628662
     1     0.463844  0.667742
     2     0.292325  0.768051
```

Which was created by saving a multi-index pandas DataFrame via `file.write(df.to_sring)`.
Now, I want to reverse this operation. But when I try

```py
pandas.read_csv(data, sep=r'\s+', index_col=[0, 1])
```

it throws an error `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 3, saw 4`

Here is a small MWE:

```py
import pandas
import numpy as np
from itertools import product
df1 = pandas.DataFrame(product(['a', 'b'], range(3)), columns=['idx1', 'idx2'])
df2 = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.rand(6, 2), columns=['col1', 'col2'])
df  = pandas.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
df.set_index(['idx1','idx2'], inplace=True)
df.to_csv('test.dat', sep=' ')
with open('test2.dat', 'w') as file:
    file.write(df.to_string())
```

Note that `test.dat` which was saved via `pandas.to_csv()` can barely be counted as 'human readable' compared to `test2.dat`

**test.dat:**

```
idx1 idx2 col1 col2
a 0 0.2567883353169065 0.862770538437793
a 1 0.40994403619942743 0.7851591115509821
a 2 0.8227727216889246 0.9553088749178045
b 0 0.1592133339255788 0.6286622783546136
b 1 0.4638439474864856 0.6677423709343185
b 2 0.2923252978245071 0.7680513714069206
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) and set columns names by list comprehension:

```
df = pd.read_fwf('file.csv', header=[0,1])
df.columns = [y for x in df.columns for y in x if not 'Unnamed' in y]

#replace missing values by first column
df.iloc[:, 0] = df.iloc[:, 0].ffill().astype(int)
#set first 2 columns to MultiIndex
df = df.set_index(df.columns[:2].tolist())
print (df)
             col1    col2
idx1 idx2                
1    1     0.1234  0.2345
     2     0.4567  0.2345
     3     0.1244  0.5332
2    1     0.4213  0.5233
     2     0.5423  0.5423
     3     0.5235  0.6233
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The format comes from saving the exact same DataFrame via `file.write(df.to_string())`. The reason for this is that I want to save the data in human readable form. It seems unfortunate that pandas doesn't offer a reverse to `to_string` when using multi-indices.

Comment: @Hyperplane - No, need `df = df.to_csv(file)`, then `read_csv` working nice.

Comment: But the standard csv is definitely not human readable. I really want to use whitespace as delimiters and the nice vertical alignment that to_string offers.

Comment: @Hyperplane Added possible solution, but pandas inverse function for read file created by `df.to_string()` not exist.

Comment: See my edit. `to_csv` doesn't really work for me because the output is not really human readable. (Especially compared with the output of `to_string`). Anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: @Hyperplane - Added better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I settled on using a slight variation of jezrael's code, which automatically takes care of the number of indices. 
Note that `df.columns` has the initially the form `[(x1,y1), (x2,y2), ..., (xn, yn)]`, where `n` is the number of columns, `xi` is the label of the column `i` in the first header row, and `yi` the one of the second header row.

```py
df = pandas.read_fwf(f, header=[0,1])
cols = [x for x,_ in df.columns if 'Unnamed' not in x]
idxs = [y for _,y in df.columns if 'Unnamed' not in y]
df.columns = idxs + cols
df[idxs] = df[idxs].ffill()
df.set_index(idxs, inplace=True)
```